# How do I track data changes in external file with composition APi in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a vue which I'm importing from another file however I'm having trouble getting vue to track when the data changes here my code

**System.JS**

```
export let loggedIn = false;
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loginStatus"> ...
</template>

<script>
import { loggedIn } from "./snippets/system";
export default {
  setup() {
    init();
    let loginStatus = ref(loggedIn);    

    watch(loggedIn, (currentValue) => {
        loginStatus.value = currentValue;
        ...
    });

    return {    
      loginStatus      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You may use [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) to store the login status in your Vue3 project which is reactive instead of the current way

Comment: Ah perfect thats exactly what I needed. I didn't know vue didn't have state management by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create composable:

**system.js**

```
export function useSystem() {
  const loginStatus = ref(false);

  return {
    loginStatus
  }  
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loginStatus"> ...
</template>

<script>
import { useSystem } from "./system.js";

export default {
  setup() {
    init();
    const { loginStatus } = useSystem();

    watch(loginStatus, (currentValue) => {
        ...
    });

    return {    
      loginStatus      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up using pinia but this worked as well. Thanks